# Exclude duplicate results from self related table using entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, self-reference

I need to create hierarchical tree from accounts for a financial accounting web-api software I created a table with self relationship but get duplicate records.

Data model:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public int AccountCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    
    public int AccountParentCode { get; set; }
    public int? AccountParentId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Account AccountParent { get; set; }
            
    public ICollection<Account> AccountChields { get; set; }
}
```

return the value to api:

```
return _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();
```

My output:

```
    [  {
    "accountId": 147,
    "accountCode": 1,
    "accountName": "Test1",
    "accountParentCode": 0,
    "accountParentId": null,
    "accountChields": [
      {
        "accountId": 149,
        "accountCode": 11,
        "accountName": "Test11",
        "accountParentCode": 1,
        "accountParentId": 147,
        "accountChields": [
          {
            "accountId": 152,
            "accountCode": 113,
            "accountName": "Test113",
            "accountParentCode": 11,
            "accountParentId": 149,
            "accountChields": null
          },
          {
            "accountId": 153,
            "accountCode": 114,
            "accountName": "Test114",
            "accountParentCode": 11,
            "accountParentId": 149,
            "accountChields": null
          },
          {
            "accountId": 154,
            "accountCode": 115,
            "accountName": "Test115",
            "accountParentCode": 11,
            "accountParentId": 149,
            "accountChields": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "accountId": 150,
        "accountCode": 16,
        "accountName": "Test16",
        "accountParentCode": 1,
        "accountParentId": 147,
        "accountChields": null
      },
      {
        "accountId": 151,
        "accountCode": 18,
        "accountName": "Test18",
        "accountParentCode": 1,
        "accountParentId": 147,
        "accountChields": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accountId": 148,
    "accountCode": 2,
    "accountName": "Test2",
    "accountParentCode": 0,
    "accountParentId": null,
    "accountChields": null
  },
  {
    "accountId": 149,
    "accountCode": 11,
    "accountName": "Test11",
    "accountParentCode": 1,
    "accountParentId": 147,
    "accountChields": [
      {
        "accountId": 152,
        "accountCode": 113,
        "accountName": "Test113",
        "accountParentCode": 11,
        "accountParentId": 149,
        "accountChields": null
      },
      {
        "accountId": 153,
        "accountCode": 114,
        "accountName": "Test114",
        "accountParentCode": 11,
        "accountParentId": 149,
        "accountChields": null
      },
      {
        "accountId": 154,
        "accountCode": 115,
        "accountName": "Test115",
        "accountParentCode": 11,
        "accountParentId": 149,
        "accountChields": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accountId": 150,
    "accountCode": 16,
    "accountName": "Test16",
    "accountParentCode": 1,
    "accountParentId": 147,
    "accountChields": null
  },
  {
    "accountId": 151,
    "accountCode": 18,
    "accountName": "Test18",
    "accountParentCode": 1,
    "accountParentId": 147,
    "accountChields": null
  },
  {
    "accountId": 152,
    "accountCode": 113,
    "accountName": "Test113",
    "accountParentCode": 11,
    "accountParentId": 149,
    "accountChields": null
  },
  {
    "accountId": 153,
    "accountCode": 114,
    "accountName": "Test114",
    "accountParentCode": 11,
    "accountParentId": 149,
    "accountChields": null
  },
  {
    "accountId": 154,
    "accountCode": 115,
    "accountName": "Test115",
    "accountParentCode": 11,
    "accountParentId": 149,
    "accountChields": null
  }
]
```

I'm new to using .Net technology, is there a way to accomplish this task or do I have to change the way I think about setting up the database?

Thak you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a table with self relationship but get duplicate records

You can **find all the root elements** first, and then **find the corresponding child elements** in turn.

In addition, you do **not need** the **AccountParentCode property**, you can **get the ParentCode** of the parent element **through AccountParent**.

Below is an example, you can refer to it.

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public DailyCoreMVCDemoContext db;
    public ValuesController(DailyCoreMVCDemoContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> test()
    {
        var allrootAccount = await db.Accounts.Where(m => m.AccountParentId == null).ToListAsync();
        var test = await db.Accounts.ToListAsync();
        allrootAccount.ForEach(t =>
        {
            t.AccountChields = GetSubordinateAccounts(test, t);
        });
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allrootAccount, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
        return result;
    }
    //a recursive method to get all subordinate Accounts
    public static List<Account> GetSubordinateAccounts(List<Account> allAccounts, Account superordinateAccount)
    {
        var result = new List<Account>();
        var subordinate = allAccounts.Where(a => a.AccountParentId == superordinateAccount.AccountId & a.AccountId != a.AccountParentId).ToList();
        if (subordinate.Count != 0)
        {
            result.AddRange(subordinate);
            foreach (var subo in subordinate)
            {
                result.AddRange(GetSubordinateAccounts(subordinate, subo));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it works for me but I don't know why I get just tow level of accounts?!

Comment: "I don't know why I get just tow level of accounts" What does this sentence mean, can you describe it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to clean the data in database but you can use this code to exclude duplicate data :

```
 _context.Accounts.Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it but not work and return same results.

Comment: How did you create hierarchical tree? This code only retrieve data as is in SQL table.